# What exactly is meant by "side-effects" of code?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, volatile

The following quote is taken from [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

I am unable to understand the last line of the paragraph (which I have applied a bold font to). **What is meant by *side-effects* of code?**

> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference. However, this does not eliminate all need to synchronize atomic actions, because memory consistency errors are still possible. Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads. What's more, **it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169232/java-volatile-and-side-effects?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Side-effect" here means that the thread updates some memory location outside of its own stack. Basically that means that it changed the state of some object on the heap.

The synchronization mechanism that ensures that the `volatile` field gets published properly also results (as a side-effect, hihi) in the same guarantee for any memory writes that the other thread did before it updated that field.

Answer (score 1):

A side effect refers simply to the modification of some kind of state - for instance:

- Changing the value of a variable;
- Writing some data to disk;
- Enabling or disabling a button in the User Interface.

So in the last line, the thread would see any changes of state caused by a side effect of the code beyond just that of the volatile variable being read.

Comment: I assume in this context "side effects" refers specifically to memory state.