# Does the compareAndSet return value guarantees a "Happens before" relationship?

Tags: java, atomic, synchronized, compare-and-swap, spinlock

I am sure many questions have been asked on this subject, but I guess all of them have dodge me.

My question arises since I've looked variations of the same code, in which a spin lock is combined with an atomic compareAndSet, and I guess the point is to ensure a happens before relationship.

A .get() is performed at the begining of the loop, this ref will serve as "expect", if at the end of the transaction the value is still the same as when it began, then return.

The only thing for which the return of the compareAndSet is used for is to return from the loop.

If Java locks are supposed to be adaptive, meaning they combine both spin and context switching, wouldn't it be more convenient to just synchronize the body instead of doing a doble nested spin lock since the compareAndSet is doing a second loop within it?

It seems the atomic classes could have placed a method with a function parameter in order to perform custom transactions instead of forcing people to do outer loops, the lack of this option is part of the reason why I've been so puzzled by the compareAndSet return, since it seems the return value serves the same purpose, but I guess not.

Comment: `compareAndSet` does no loop within it - it maps 1:1 to a low level feature present on many current processers (for example on Intel processors: [CMPXCHG](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_41.html)). This low level feature just doesn't support "custom transactions" - this is the job of the higher level code.

Comment: `if at the end of the transaction the value is the same` ... makes me you might want to look at StampedLock

Answer (score 2):

Following the javadoc of [`compareAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet(int,int)) makes clear the JVM treats these the same as `volatile` for which we can find many descriptions including here on SO: [Java volatile and side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169232/java-volatile-and-side-effects).

Short answer: yes